# How to check if a record is already present in the DataView? C#

Tags: c#

I have a DataView which has two columns: `ContactID`, and `Name`

How can I check if a particular `ContactID` is already existing in the DataView?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [DataView.FindRows Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.findrows.aspx)  or maybe [DataView.Find Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.find%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Wait, Say what? Can you access any other sites? Search for the method names I provided.

Answer (score 0):

The DataView has a method called FindRows, this can be used to search for a specific contactID, for example...

```
var table = new DataTable();
var column = new DataColumn("Id", typeof (int));

table.Columns.Add(column);
table.PrimaryKey = new[] {column}; // Unique Constraint

var row = table.NewRow();
row["Id"] = 100;
table.Rows.Add(row);

row = table.NewRow();
row["Id"] = 200;
table.Rows.Add(row);

var view = new DataView(table) { ApplyDefaultSort = true };
var rows = view.FindRows(200);

foreach(var r in rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r["Id"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Following code to Find the row in the Dataview

```
        //Your original Table Which consist of Data
        DataTable dtProducts = new DataTable();
        //Add the DataTable to DataView
        DataView ProductDataView = new DataView(dtProducts);
        ProductDataView.RowFilter = "";
        ProductDataView.Sort = "ProdId";
        int recordIndex = -1;
        //In the Find Row Method pass the Column 
        //value which you want to find
        recordIndex = ProductDataView.Find(1);
        if (recordIndex > -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Row Found");
        }
```